# How to convert this physics2d raycast with ^ code to physics raycast

Tags: unity, c#, physics

While searching on the net I encountered a piece of code in a tutorial I want to use in my game but don't know how to convert it to physics.raycast (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1i1hTLU6JTY)

it's about the following piece of code I want to convert:

```css
RaycastHit2D maxSlopeHitLeft = Physics2D.Raycast (raycastOrigins.bottomLeft, Vector2.down, Mathf.Abs (moveAmount.y) + skinWidth, collisionMask);
RaycastHit2D maxSlopeHitRight = Physics2D.Raycast (raycastOrigins.bottomRight, Vector2.down, Mathf.Abs (moveAmount.y) + skinWidth, collisionMask);
if (maxSlopeHitLeft ^ maxSlopeHitRight) {
 SlideDownMaxSlope (maxSlopeHitLeft, ref moveAmount);
 SlideDownMaxSlope (maxSlopeHitRight, ref moveAmount);
}
```

I especially don't understand the use of ^, isn't it the same as saying

```
if((!maxSlopeHitLeft && maxSlopeHitRight) || (maxSlopeHitLeft && !maxSlopeHitRight))
```

I hope someone can help me with the 1st piece of code.

I tried to convert the code myself as follow

```
RaycastHit maxSlopeHitLeft, maxSlopeHitRight; 
if(Physics.Raycast (raycastOrigins.bottomLeft, Vector2.down, out maxSlopeHitLeft, Mathf.Abs (moveAmount.y) + skinWidth, collisionMask) ^ Physics.Raycast (raycastOrigins.bottomRight, Vector2.down, out maxSlopeHitRight, Mathf.Abs (moveAmount.y) + skinWidth, collisionMask)) { 
SlideDownMaxSlope (maxSlopeHitLeft, ref moveAmount); 
SlideDownMaxSlope (maxSlopeHitRight, ref moveAmount); 
}
```

when my player reaches an edge of a platform it freezes all movement, while in the source tutorial it doesn't

Here is the SlideDownMaxSlope method, it check whether the angle is high enough to slide and calculates the horizontal moving amount

```
void SlideDownMaxSlope(RaycastHit Hit, ref Vector3 MoveAmount){
    float SlopeAngle = Vector3.Angle (Hit.normal, Vector3.up);
    if (SlopeAngle > MaxSlopeAngle) {
        MoveAmount.x = Mathf.Sign (Hit.normal.x) * (Mathf.Abs (MoveAmount.y) - Hit.distance) / Mathf.Tan (SlopeAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

        CI.SlopeAngle = SlopeAngle;
        CI.SlideDownSlope = true;
        CI.SlopeNormal = Hit.normal;
    }
}
```

plus in an update function of another script there is a line for calculating the vertical moving amount

```
if(Grounded) {
    if (PCS.CI.SlideDownSlope) {
        Velocity.y += PCS.CI.SlopeNormal.y * -Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    } else {
        Velocity.y = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your interpretation of the `^` Exclusive Or (XOR) is correct. What problem are you having using this code or converting it to use 3D raycasts?

Comment: @DMGregory double check, that interpretation is wrong because the two expressions are the same

Comment: i tried to convert the code as follow

RaycastHit maxSlopeHitLeft, maxSlopeHitRight;
if(Physics.Raycast (raycastOrigins.bottomLeft, Vector2.down, out maxSlopeHitLeft,  Mathf.Abs (moveAmount.y) + skinWidth, collisionMask) ^ Physics.Raycast (raycastOrigins.bottomRight, Vector2.down, out maxSlopeHitRight,  Mathf.Abs (moveAmount.y) + skinWidth, collisionMask)) {
 SlideDownMaxSlope (maxSlopeHitLeft, ref moveAmount);
 SlideDownMaxSlope (maxSlopeHitRight, ref moveAmount);
}


when my player reaches an edge of a platform it freezes all movement, while in the source tutorial it doesn't

Comment: sorry about it.

Comment: I'm sorry but what game are we talking about? 2.5d? What are the degrees of freedom? Converting from 2d to 3d is not just code, can you explain the situation a little bit better?

Comment: yes, it's a 2.5d game , the game physics  is more or less like  super mario

Comment: Which axis is right/left? Which axis is up/down?

Comment: horizontal/xaxis is left/right,  vertical/yaxis is up/down like old 2d platformers

Comment: Can you include the SlideDownMaxSlope method so we can see what it's doing?

Comment: never mind, I think I found the problem. Just need to add an extra hit check to find out which raycast did hit something and it works. anyway, thanks to everyone who tries to help

Comment: @Ken please post your solution as an answer if you've solved it. Also, remember to pick it as the answer (checkmark button under the voting buttons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding the line *if(Hit.collider != null) {* player will freeze all movement when reaching an edge. Because there are 2 raycasthit involved in the process of detecting slopes, I added an if statement to filter out the 1 raycast that actually does hit a slope.

```
RaycastHit maxSlopeHitLeft, maxSlopeHitRight; 
if(Physics.Raycast (raycastOrigins.bottomLeft, Vector2.down, out maxSlopeHitLeft, Mathf.Abs (moveAmount.y) + skinWidth, collisionMask) ^ Physics.Raycast (raycastOrigins.bottomRight, Vector2.down, out maxSlopeHitRight, Mathf.Abs (moveAmount.y) + skinWidth, collisionMask)) { 
SlideDownMaxSlope (maxSlopeHitLeft, ref moveAmount); 
SlideDownMaxSlope (maxSlopeHitRight, ref moveAmount); 
}

void SlideDownMaxSlope(RaycastHit Hit, ref Vector3 MoveAmount){
    if(Hit.collider != null) {
    float SlopeAngle = Vector3.Angle (Hit.normal, Vector3.up);
        if (SlopeAngle > MaxSlopeAngle) {
            MoveAmount.x = Mathf.Sign (Hit.normal.x) * (Mathf.Abs (MoveAmount.y) - Hit.distance) / Mathf.Tan (SlopeAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

            CI.SlopeAngle = SlopeAngle;
            CI.SlideDownSlope = true;
            CI.SlopeNormal = Hit.normal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included a little description about what you changed and why that fixed the problem. That way other users with a similar problem that's not exactly the same can learn from your problem-solving process.